# SqlCommand parameters aren't working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Consider the following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connection string");

SqlCommand ourCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format(
    @"SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE '@FL1'"), conn);
ourCommand.CommandTimeout = 6000;

ourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FL1", TextBox1.Text);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(ourCommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

The problem is that `datatable` is empty - which means the command either was not executed or incorrect query was generated. What am I missing? Connection and query are valid. The command without parameter also works. Database engine is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from around the parameter '@FL1' --> @FL1

Comment: Do you get results when running the same query (manually adding the value for the parameter) from the SQL Management Studio?

Comment: What data are you passing from TextBox1.Text? Is it something like "%sometext%"? I.e. if you execute query by itself with the same parameter (in SSMS for example) - does it return results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've put the parameter name in quotes, so it's being treated as a *value*, not as a parameter. Try this instead:

```
"SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE @FL1"
```

(I'd actually expect your existing code to throw an exception given that you're supplying more parameters than are in the SQL...)

As noted in comments, you don't need the `string.Format` either.

Comment: And that `string.Format` doesn't have an overload that only takes a single parameter...

Comment: Thanks to all, that's correct. One more question: will such usage of parameters protect from SQL injection?

Comment: @Oded: Yes it does - because of the params array. `String.Format("foo")` is equivalent to `String.Format("Foo", new object[])`

Comment: @seeker: Yes, it's fine - the value isn't part of the SQL, hence there's no injection risk.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I see. Didn't consider that the compiler will send an empty array if nothing was supplied...

Answer (score 5):

Your query is not a well formatted query.

Instead of:

```
String.Format(
    @"SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE '@FL1'")
```

Use:

```
"SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE @FL1"
```

Note that there is no need for `string.Format`, nor to enclose the parameter name in `''` and since there is nothing to escape in the string, no need for it to be a verbatim string literal (using the `@`), as Jon commented.

Comment: If parameter will be equal to "'" (apostrophe) then the exception will be thrown and that also mean that it's possible to perform sql injection. How to protect that?

Comment: @seeker - No, it will not be vulnerable. Try it. The ADO libraries will escape the single quotes and you will not have a problem.

Comment: Yes, that's true. And one more question: what is the best way to store connection strings? In application as string or in web.config?

Comment: @seeker - `web.config` is the standard. It has a `connectionStrings` section just for this. And it is then configurable, which most application do need.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the line to this (remove the tick marks sorrounding @FL1)

```
SqlCommand ourCommand=new SqlCommand(
             "SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE @FL1",conn);
```

Comment: Drop the `string.Format` and you are there.

Comment: @Oded ha! was trying to see if anyone was paying attention  ;)  didn't even notice that myself  :D  fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you are using parameters, you don't need to use single quotes.
Take a look on lesson [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you don't need the string.format or the `@`'s (you have no escaped chars, your string are on one line, and you aren't using parameterized strings, so there's no reason for either one) **Then, you don't need the quotes around @FL1**. SqlCommand parses entire string for `@`'s, not for substrings delimited by quotes. The final code, I believe, should look like this:

```
SqlCommand ourCommand=new SqlCommand("SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE @FL1",conn);
```

Everything else I think you can keep the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force concatenation with percent `%` ->

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 LIKE **'%'** + @FL1 + **'%'**
```