# Do SQLite parameters need to be encapsulated in ''

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I use System.Data.Sqlite for accessing a sqlite3 database.

I often use statements like

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Properties (name, value) VALUES(@name, @value)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Database Format")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The parameter value can be arbitrary, so they may contain whitespace. Is the API clever enough to automatically encapsulate these in `' '` or should I do this myself like

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Properties (name, value) VALUES('@name', '@value')"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Database Format")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I am not deeply schooled in SQL syntax and so on so I don't know what is really valid and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to wrap sql command parameter with single-quotes.

Wrapping the parameter may even backfire causing it not recognized as parameter but *value*, like what happen to OP in this other SO post : [SqlCommand parameters aren't working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779861/sqlcommand-parameters-arent-working-properly)

Comment: I see. I will look into this, nice find.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if Sqlite has any special command parsing abilities but SQL in general expects/needs the single quotes for some data types.

Generally types like numbers and dates don’t need to be wrapped in single quotes but data types that can contain white space need to be wrapped.

The short answer is that if you are not sure, wrap it and then test.

EDIT: Using parameters is a little different but again, try it and then test.

Comment: Testing is of course always necessary. However, being a novice, some clearer definitions for predicting behaviour is important as well, especially if your beta testing crowd is very limited ;-)